# Как получить ссылку, через которую сайт в браузере хочет запустить приложение?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, url, protocol

После нажатия синей кнопки появляется такое окно для запуска приложения. Как получить ссылку с протоколом на открытие Epic Games Launcher? На самой кнопке в html ссылки нет.
[image]

В адресной строке ссылка не появляется, потому что это не адрес страницы. Даже если удерживать `ctrl`, чтобы она открылась в новой вкладке, она всё равно открывается в текущей вкладке.

1. Как узнать эту ссылку средствами `JavaScript`?
2. Где в Windows хранятся эти все протоколы?
3. Можно ли сделать, чтобы такая ссылка работала через адресную строку?

Answer (score 0):

У меня нет Epic, но для других работает так: открой devtools в хроме (ctrl + shift + I), перейди на вкладку `Network`, там выбери в фильтре `All`, чтобы видеть всю активность, и перезагрузи страницу. Там при загрузке попапа появится и информация о ридеректе (будет выделено красным, скорей всего). Нажми на него, будет и полная ссылка, типа `zoommtg://yandex.zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=9717...` (эта для Zoom).

Comment: Не могу перезагрузить, потому что это окно появляется только один раз — после получения игры (в том числе бесплатной). Где-то же должен быть в Windows (может, в реестре) этот протокол.

Comment: Белое окно открывается даже без подключения к интернету. Может, такие ссылки в `Network` не отображаются.

Comment: Вопрос обновлен.